# CFTHREAD CFHTTP timeout

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Basically I have a job scheduling engine that executes cfhttp calls from within a cfthread tag.  This is so multiple jobs can run concurrently.  Basically what I want to be able to do is extend the timeout period beyond what the administrator's default is on some of my cfhttp calls so that I can let them finish and get the results from the page I'm calling.  But that's not happening.

My CF Admin Request Timeout setting is 30 seconds. I have two files.  The first is called 'MyThreadedCFHTTP.cfm':

```
<cfthread action="run" name="job_#CreateUUID()#">
    <cfsetting requesttimeout="400" >
    <cflog text="Web Service Request: Starting" file="JobSchedulerTest" >  

    <!--- Lets do our cfhttp call --->
    <cfset var httpResults = ""/>
    <cfhttp method="get" url="http://localhost:8500/sessiontesting/CFHTTPRequestTimeOut/GetResults.cfm?RequestTime=400" result="httpResults" timeout="400"> 

    <cflog text="Web Service Result: #httpResults.FileContent#" file="JobSchedulerTest" >    
</cfthread>**strong text**
```

My cfm file that is called is 'GetResults.cfm'.  It just sleeps for 59 seconds before doing anything.

```
<cfsetting requesttimeout="400"/>
<cfset sleep(59000)/>
```

This doesn't work as expected.  The cfhttp call, though it has has timeout of 400 seconds and I have a cfsetting/requesttimeout value right before it, will abort after 30 seconds with a Connection Timeout message.  This is the servers default setting.  Now whats interesting is if you remove the  tags, the call will finish successfully.

I'm assuming this has something to do when the cfhttp call is threaded its executing within some completely new context and so it can only see the administrator's request timeout value.  But I'm just guessing.

Can someone help me figure a solution here.  I could remove the timeout value from the administrator, but I really hate to have to do that as I could would much prefer to keep that and only override it when I explicitly say so.

Comment: It's possible that the page you are trying to get with cfhttp is the one timing out.  But I'm guessing.

Comment: @Dan,  The file I'm calling is the 'GetResults.cfm' page which has the code: <cfsetting requesttimeout="400"/>
<cfset sleep(59000)/>.  This page doesn't timeout cause I have the requesttimeout value set in that file.  The weird thing is that if I remove the 'cfthread' tags around the code above and call the page everything runs as expected, with no timeouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have any personal experience with this but after some searching it seems that the `<cfsetting requesttimeout="">` code is not honored by the `<cfthread>` tag.  See the following references that I found.

**Note that I am not suggesting you make the changes that they detail like disabling the request timeout setting in the ColdFusion administrator. I don't think that is a good idea.**  I am just passing along this information that I found. The gist being that the `<cfthread>` tag does not support the `<cfsetting requesttimeout="">` option. So you probably need to find another way to do what you need or optimize your code to finish before the set timeout.

[cfthread and request timeout in coldfusion](http://blogs.alagukannan.com/2010/04/28/cfthread-and-request-timeout-in-coldfusion/)

> In the process I found the following after some testing and playing around:
>
> 1. The CFthread basically respects the CF admin panel timeout if it’s set and kills the thread after the timeout period.
> 2. It doesn’t respect the request timeout set using the CFsetting tag in onRequestStart or any where in the code.
> 3. There are still certain tags that don’t obey the CFthread request timeout,they are CFFTP,CFEXECUTE, CFX tags and CFStoredProc.

[Increase request timeout for a thread in CFML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390148/increase-request-timeout-for-a-thread-in-cfml)

> As you can see, I've tried adding a `<cfsetting requestTimeout=240 />` to the top of the thread to try and make it live longer... no dice.

[Am I utilizing <cfthread> correctly for this solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148315/am-i-utilizing-cfthread-correctly-for-this-solution)

> As for thread timeouts - you can specify a max time to wait for threads you created to rejoin page execution, but AFAIK there is no way to put a timeout (like a page request timeout) on the thread you created.

And Charlie Arehart has a pretty good article on ColdFusion request timeouts in general - [CF911: Lies, Damned Lies, and CF Request Timeouts...What You May Not Realize](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2010/10/15/lies_damned_lies_and_cf_timeouts)

Comment: @Miquel-F,  totally hear ya, but I already did that.  If you look at the line right after my starting cfthread tag, you will see I have set the requesttimeout to 400.  It doesn't matter if i put that <cfsettting requesttimeout=400/> before or after the cfthread tag, I get the same results, which is cfhttp times out.  Other ideas?

Comment: @user2592724 - But that is the point that I am trying to make... and again this is only based on searching, I do not have any personal experience with this.  The `<cfthread>` tag ignores the `<cfsetting requesttimeout="">` tag. It will always timeout based on the setting in the ColdFusion administrator.

Comment: My response was to the first post you made of 'Your <cfsetting requesttimeout="400"/> code needs to go in the calling template, the one making the cfhttp calls; MyThreadedCFHTTP.cfm in your example. Not in the page that is being called.'.  Your updated one makes a lot of sense.  Its interesting because the cfthread will run as long as it needs to. Its the cfhttp tag that times out based on the admin setting.  I think I might need to follow the recommendation in the first link.  Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Oh, right. I had answered incorrectly at first. After re-reading your code I saw that you were doing what I mentioned. Then I began searching and found the info above so I updated my answer. **be careful disabling the timeout setting in the administrator** I would be hesitant to do that.